# TypeScript Project - SystemJS

Tags: typescript, npm, systemjs

I'm trying to create a new TypeScript project.

I'd like it to be as straightforward and lightweight as possible without any unnecessarily complex configurations, while meeting these requirements:

-Using npm

-Using TypeScript

-Using import statements, e.g.

```
import { A, B } from 'module';
```

-Bundle all dependencies from node_modules that were imported using import statements into /build for production

-Compile project source into a single outFile and put it in /build

-Load dependencies at runtime according to imports made using import statements

-Using SystemJS, since I understood it's in the process of becoming the standard module loader

**So far I created a new project:**

-Used npm - installed a framework and its typings for TypeScript

-Compiling using tsc (tsconfig.json) via Visual Studio Code

-tsconfig.json "module": "system" (SystemJS)

-I can write import statements (since module is set to "system")

-tsconfig.json "outFile": "../build/app.js" - compiles project source into a single outFile and puts it in "build" dir

**What I'm missing is:**

-Bundle all dependencies from node_modules that were imported using import statements into /build for production

-Load dependencies at runtime according to imports made using import statements

I don't have any experience with setting up and configuring module loaders.

**Could you please help point me in the right direction?**

Searching any of these subjects brings up results and npm modules I could use, but things can get too complex too fast and it'll take me too much time playing around to understand what I'm doing and what needs to be done, so any advice from someone who knows how to best approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think both your problems can be solved by using [jspm](http://jspm.io/). It is using systemjs as module loader and takes away from you the burden of configuring and maintaining all packages paths, extensions, etc that are required by systemjs configuration.

Specifically answering your question:

1. jspm will keep all your client dependencies in one separate folder (jspm_packages) therefore in order to prepare your dependencies for deploy all you need to do is copy this folder to the target location.
2. jspm will produce config.js for you containing all configuration of all used (including nested) packages

Start off with this [user guide](http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html) - it is very clear and will allow you to configure jspm in no time.

Comment: I just tried jspm, it looks like there's a lot to learn in it and many issues to tackle (typescript doesn't recognize jspm path by default in imports, bundling typescript for production has issues...),

Doesn't npm have some command to bundle all dependencies into a single bundle.js or something similar?

Comment: To keep typescript/ide happy - just use ordinary dependencies in package.json. Noone prohibit you from having both. Jspm will take care of module loading client side. Never had issues with deploys either. And i do not think there is a command in npm to bundle package - its not a webpack afterall.

Comment: Okay I did that, ts is now able to find it. Will jspm load and bundle npm dependencies that were not installed via jspm? Deploy - `jspm bundle` expects a .js file, I guess I should point it to a file compiled by .ts? Even when I do that I have errors, but let's put them aside for a moment. I guess I also need to run this from a local server in order to avoid cross-origin errors as well. Is it possible to use import statements without depending on a module loader like systemjs? I don't even mind loading the libraries manually frankly, I just like the syntax.

Comment: The jspm bundle error is:
`err  TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
         at Trace.getLoadDependencies (C:\Users\royib\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jspm\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\trace.js:957:12)`

Comment: I think you are trying to jump over too many things at once. Start with preparing simple test project with typescript and jspm. Do not think about bundling yet. There is a nice example to start with: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/jspm. When this is done and you feel comfortable and understand what it does and how it works - proceed with bundling.

Comment: I guess you are right. I used jspm-server. My index.html loads my build/app.js (compiled from src/app.ts). The contents of app are never executed. Only app.js is loaded, in network I don't see the node_modules related dist .js files loaded. In app.js I also don't see the import I made to a module in app.ts, so it's like SystemJS got no way to know it should load it. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: This is my index.html
`<!doctype html>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('build/app.js');
  </script>`

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Its hard to give you any advice taking into account that minimum amount of actual code you have provided. I can only repeat myself and recommend you to take minimum working project (from the link I gave above), strictly follow its readme and get working solution. Then step by step modify it to your needs.